# VSCode Pytest Module Not Found Error - how to setup?

Tags: visual-studio-code, pytest

**Problem:** I have the following repo structure:

```
src
  - etl
       - main.py
       - init.py
tests
  - init.py
  - conftest.py
  - test_main.py
```

When I use vscode testing plugin for detecting tests I got the following error:
`ModuleNotFoundError No module named etl`. The error also prompts when using command line `python -m pytest tests`

```
# conftest.py
from etl.main import job

...
```

**Question:** Any ideas why this is not working in VSCode or what I need to adjust?

Comment: Shouldn't your `init.py` files be named `__init__.py` for proper package discovery?